# Consuming webservice by SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, json, web-services

I am using sql server 2016 to consume webservice through store procedure. I have a webservice in JSON returning the following:

```
["Name":"Rebecca","email":"rebecca@hotmail.com","ra":"12345"},
{"name":"Caroline","email":"caroline@hotmail.com","ra":"23456"},
{"name":"Vanessa","email":"vanessa@yahoo.com.br","ra":"99999"}]
```

I can consume it by passing a variable. If I leave my webservice to receive a parameter and pass it I can return the name and email of the student. But if I leave my webservice without the need to receive parameter and remove the procedure parameter pass and execute, my procedure returns null. What do I need to change in my code to be able to return the complete list of students my webservice exposes?

Here's my code:

```
create PROCEDURE webservice_parametros (@RA as varchar (5))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OBJ INT;
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @RESPONSE VARCHAR(8000);

SET @URL = 'http://dominio:8080/v1/alunos/' + @RA
EXEC SP_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @OBJ out
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @URL, FALSE
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'SEND'
exec SP_OAGETPROPERTY @OBJ, 'responseText', @RESPONSE out
EXEC SP_OADESTROY @OBJ

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.nome') as nome,
       JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.email') as email

END     

execute webservice_parametros '12345'
```

My code that returns NULL

```
create PROCEDURE webservice
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OBJ INT;
DECLARE @URL VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @RESPONSE VARCHAR(8000);

SET @URL = 'http://dominio:8080/v1/alunos/'
EXEC SP_OACREATE 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @OBJ out
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'OPEN', NULL, 'GET', @URL, FALSE
EXEC SP_OAMETHOD @OBJ, 'SEND'
exec SP_OAGETPROPERTY @OBJ, 'responseText', @RESPONSE out
EXEC SP_OADESTROY @OBJ

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.nome') as nome,
       JSON_VALUE(@RESPONSE, '$.email') as email

END     

execute webservice
```